# Why can't I write to a file despite using "append" mode?

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to create a basic login system with Python that only includes a username. Here is a snippet of what I'm having issues with.

I added a few usernames to the .txt file and it can find conflicts or login properly but it can't actually register a username. I've done some research and am opening the file in "append" mode and using the `write` command.

```
def register():
   file1 = open("C:/test/User_Dat.txt", "a")
   global username
   username = str(input("Please enter a username \n")).lower()
   readfile = file1.read()
   if username in readfile: 
        print('The user', username, 'has already been created.')
        welcome()
   else: 
        print('The user', username, 'has been created!')
        file1.write(username)
        file1.write("\n")
        file1.close()
        login()
```

But I still get an error like this:

> io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable

Why is the file not writable?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED:

You are opening file in reading mode. Fix this line as follows:

```
file1 = open("C:/test/User_Dat.txt", "r+")
```

Documentation:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Comment: I'm sorry. I posted an old snippet of code I actually had that changed. That's partially why I'm confused. It appears to be an error related to the line that states

```
   readfile = file1.read()
```

Comment: That breaks the first part of OP's code, where they're reading the file to determine if the entered username already exists. I believe that opening the file with mode "r+" instead would work with the code as written.

Comment: @Eric - Thank you. R+ worked for me. I accidentally posted an older version of the code with "r", when I was actually using "a" before I even posted this. Of course people took the opportunity to dogpile on before I edited it. 

However what you stated is correct/makes sense/most importantly: works. Thank you so much.